# Sending data to Slack Hook through python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, webhooks, slack-api

Based on Slack documentation, each new block element is a new message.

https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts

In such a case, the below example would send one message.

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "This is a plain text section block.",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, two messages:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "This is a plain text section block.",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "This is a plain text section block.",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**My goal** - is to generate such a JSON/Dictionary structure in Python, from two lists and then send it all as separate messages, as shown in the second case, but instead of two, as many elements as there are.

```
first = ['Tomato', 'Potato', 'Fish', 'Chicken']
second = ['tasty', 'good', 'nice', 'bad']

dictionary = {first[i]: second[i] for i in range(len(first))}

slackmessagexample = {"blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": food + " " + taste
            } for food, taste in dictionary.items()
    ]
}

jsonoutput = json.dumps(slackmessagexample, indent=2)

print(jsonoutput)
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": "Tomato tasty"
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": "Potato good"
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": "Fish nice"
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": "Chicken bad"
    }
  ]
}
```

This may seem silly, but I'm not able to figure out, how would one add for loop within the nested dictionary/JSON format in such case.

My final desired output should look like this:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Tomato tasty",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Potato good",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Fish nice",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Chicken bad",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! You can just add the nested dictionary in the comprehension. Also, I recommend using Python's [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function for your case when creating the `dictionary`. It creates an iterable of tuples which can be casted into `dict` directly.

As for your JSON structure, take a look at the following:

```py
import json

first = ["Tomato", "Potato", "Fish", "Chicken"]
second = ["tasty", "good", "nice", "bad"]

dictionary = dict(zip(first, second))

slackmessagexample = {
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {"type": "plain_text", "text": food + " " + taste, "emoji": True},
        }
        for food, taste in dictionary.items()
    ]
}

jsonoutput = json.dumps(slackmessagexample, indent=2)

print(jsonoutput)
```

Output:

```
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Tomato tasty",
        "emoji": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Potato good",
        "emoji": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Fish nice",
        "emoji": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Chicken bad",
        "emoji": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can finally go to sleep.